# mysql complex select query for fetching rows as column issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write select query for MySQL DB which will give me output like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLLOq.jpg)

| TEACHER_ID | Image1 | Image2 | Image3 | Image4 | Image5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 341 | 1.jpeg | 2.jpeg | 10.jpeg | 20.jpeg | 30.jpeg |
| 734 | 3.jpeg | 4.jpeg | 40.jpeg | 50.jpeg | 60.jpeg |

Following are the screen shots of the two tables from which I am trying to fetch records-
[Table-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn4jj.jpg)

[Table-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhjlx.jpg)

I have written following sql query for particular teacher_id:

```
SELECT R.SCHOOL_ID,R.TEACHER_ID,R.IMAGE_NAME REG_IMAGE_NAME,A.IMAGE_NAME 
ATT_IMAGE_NAME,A.ATTENDANCE_DT,A.ATTENDANCE_TYPE
FROM TABLE1 R (NOLOCK)
JOIN
TABLE2 A (NOLOCK)
ON R.TEACHER_ID = A.TEACHER_ID
WHERE A.TEACHER_ID = '341'
AND A.ATTENDANCE_DT = '2022-02-21'
ORDER BY A.ATTENDANCE_TYPE;
```

But I am struggling to write one which will give me required output not only for a particular teacher_id but for all.

Since I cannot add excel file here, I am attaching here table1, table2 xlsx files dummy data.
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mZS.jpg)
[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLlVv.jpg)

Please have a look and let me know in case I have missed here to add.

Adding dummy data in form of text as asked by others-
Table1:

| SCHOOL_ID | TEACHER_ID | IS_HEAD_MASTER | TAGGED_CLASS | IMAGE_NAME | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ACCURACY | CREATED_DATE | CREATED_BY | AI_IMAGE_NAME | AI_STATUS | IS_DOWNLOADED | DOWNLOADED_DATE | IS_PROCESSEED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | 341 | Y | 10.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |
| 204 | 341 | Y | 20.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |
| 204 | 341 | Y | 30.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |
| 204 | 734 | N | 40.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |
| 204 | 734 | N | 50.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |
| 204 | 734 | N | 60.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |  |

Table2:

| TEACHER_ID | TAGGED_SCHOOL_ID | ATTENDANCE_DT | ATTENDANCE_TYPE | IMAGE_NAME | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ACCURACY | CAPTURED_TIME | AI_IMAGE_NAME | AI_STATUS | IS_DOWNLOADED | DOWNLOADED_DATE | IS_PROCESSEED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 341 | 204 | 21-02-2022 | IN | 1.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 37:16.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 341 | 204 | 21-02-2022 | OUT | 2.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 80 | 55:45.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 734 | 204 | 21-02-2022 | IN | 3.jpeg | 1.3 | 2.3 | 80 | 24:24.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 734 | 204 | 21-02-2022 | OUT | 4.jpeg | 1.4 | 2.4 | 80 | 31:47.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Does the amount of images per teacher in your tables are strictly 3 and 2 respectively?

Comment: It's better if you can [post the dummy data](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71217602/edit) in textual form instead - just a small part enough to recreate the situation. It's impossible to copy & paste from an image and re-writing it will take too much time.  You may also use consider using [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) to recreate your sample data.

Comment: @Akina yes 3 images from table 1 and from table 2 there will be 2 images/teacher

Comment: Use conditional aggregation by each separate table (pivot emulation) then join by teacher.

Comment: @FanoFN I have edited the post with dummy data in text format.

Comment: Use UNION instead of JOIN. If no of images increase then use PIVOT

Comment: @FanoFN Thanks for formatting the sample data. I was not aware of this.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, I'd like to know what is `(NOLOCK)` in your query there? Also, take a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18497841c788dd9b2061c7691d8e9d0d) and tell on the current result there, how would you format it?